# Elastic: diaply logs in text (not json)

Tags: elasticsearch, logging

I am running elasticsearch (version 8.12.0) using docker-compose for development.
Logs are outputed in json and very compact and hard to read.
How can the logs be printed as somple text (and not json)?

The logs are printed via docker to stderr.

```
...

  elastic:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.12.0
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
```

Comment: Can you share how you are tailing the logs and please also share a couple of lines from the logs.

Comment: Please share the command that you used to display the logs... Are you using `docker logs -f --tail 10 container_name` ? if so also share the output and let me check

Comment: the commnd is `docker-compose up`

Comment: The output you shared is not JSON. Can you share the output you mentioned.